# jQuery click event not triggered on button inside form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, click

I have a button inside a form like this:

```
<form>
   <input type="text" />
   <input type="password" />
   <button type="button" class="btn-login">Log in</button>
 </form>
```

I am trying to trigger the button's click event by doing this in the js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.btn-login').live("click", function () {
          alert("Button clicked!");
      });
});
```

But for some reason, this is not working.

If I remove the `<form></form>` that is around the textboxes and button, the click event is triggered, but this also means that my page is not showing properly, so I wonder if there is a way to trigger the button's click event when inside the form.

Comment: Dunno why wrapping it in a `<form>` tag would break it but try using `.on('click'` instead of `.live`

Comment: seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PVMca/1/

Comment: Is this form added via ajax in DOM, as you use live

Comment: as per `http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp` `Tips and Notes Note: If you use the <button> element in an HTML form, different browsers may submit different values. Use <input> to create buttons in an HTML form.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using latest version of Jquery the try `on` instead of `live` as it is deprecated in version 1.9. If you are using version 1.7 then your code will work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.btn-login').on("click", function () {
          alert("Button clicked!");
      });
});
```

[JS Fiddle .on() example](http://jsfiddle.net/HkhAh/)

[JS Fiddle .live() example](http://jsfiddle.net/HkhAh/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick , will accept the answer as soon as I can!

Answer (score 1):

.live Function() has been removed as from jQuery 1.9 .
Reference: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Please use .on() function for binding events.
Reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/

**Solution:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.btn-login').on("click", function () {
          alert("Button clicked!");
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are using a newer version of jquery, I tested with 1.9.1 and [jQuery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) does not work (removed jquery 1.9). A simple change to [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and it sprang immediately to life.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="password" />
    <button type="button" class="btn-login">Log in</button>
</form>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn-login').on("click", function () {
        alert("Button clicked!");
    });
});
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/EbNK9/)

As a note to comments, [this is what the W3C has to say](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5)

> Buttons created with the BUTTON element function just like buttons
>   created with the INPUT element, but they offer richer rendering
>   possibilities: the BUTTON element may have content. For example, a
>   BUTTON element that contains an image functions like and may resemble
>   an INPUT element whose type is set to “image”, but the BUTTON element
>   type allows content.
>
> The Button Element - W3C

[This article demonstrates some of the differences between button and input](http://web.archive.org/web/20110721191046/http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element/)

And what of W3cschools advice?

> Tips and Notes Note: If you use the  element in an HTML form,
>   different browsers may submit different values. Use  to create
>   buttons in an HTML form.
>
> W3cschools: HTML  Tag

w3cschools are not an authorative body. As far as I can tell, the only browsers that had real issues were IE6 & IE7, so I guess their advice is a little out of date. It is possible that there are others but I could not find anything concrete. the best I could find was on [MDN <\button>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/button)

> IE7 has a bug where when submitting a form with Click me, the POST data sent will
>   result in myButton=Click me instead of myButton=foo. IE6 has an even
>   worse bug where submitting a form through a button will submit ALL
>   buttons of the form, with the same bug as IE7 This bug has been fixed
>   in IE8

Comment: as per `http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp` `Tips and Notes Note: If you use the <button> element in an HTML form, different browsers may submit different values. Use <input> to create buttons in an HTML form.`

Answer (score 0):

I think below code should work for you

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).delegate('.btn-login', "click", function () {
          alert("Button clicked!");
      });
});
```

It uses delegate from jquery, so even if it is added later in DOM via ajax, this function would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate 1.1.0 to 1.9.1 to use `.live()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.btn-login').live("click", function () {
          alert("Button clicked!");
      });
});
```

**[Working Example]** (http://jsfiddle.net/3hQbG/)

Answer (score -1):

instead of

```
<button type="button" class="btn-login">Log in</button>
```

use

```
<input type="button" class="btn-login">Log in</input>
```

Comment: www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

It's html5 code, hence valid.

Comment: as per `http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp` 
`Tips and Notes
Note: If you use the <button> element in an HTML form, different browsers may submit different values. Use <input> to create buttons in an HTML form.`

Comment: I don't think w3schools tips are authorative enough that the OP needs to change his element type.