# Button inside a form is not accessible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, event-handling

I'm trying to trigger the click event of a button inside a form using jQuery.

```js
$(".switchLang").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log("Clicked!")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline" action="">
  <button type="button" class="btn mr-3 btn-link transparent switchLang">${{index.keys.lng}}$</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn mr-3 btn-outline-light">${{index.keys.login}}$</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">${{index.keys.getStarted}}$</button>
</form>
```

The function above is not invoked!

After research, I tried many solution but nothing's work. Like adding `e.preventDefault();` inside the function also remove `.click` and replaced with `.on` and so on, but nothing works!

I have referred to this question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192190/jquery-click-event-not-triggered-on-button-inside-form).

Thanks.

---

***Solved***

I double checked my code. the html is written inside script of type text/template and this template is rendered before the jquery code. Thanks.

Comment: is it calling in `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

Comment: I placed your code in to a snippet where it appears to work correctly. Are the buttons dynamically added to the page after it loads initially?#

Comment: Hello @RoryMcCrossan thanks for you edit, yea it's inside a .ready trigger

Comment: The code you provided does work. Your problem must lie elsewhere. Are there any (invisible) content element that cover your button?

Comment: @KhaledRamadan I mean is the HTML loaded via AJAX, for example.

Comment: @KhaledRamadan Then Tuhin Hossain's anwer will help you out.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm new on the stackoverflow and approved your editing by I don't know why it's returned to the old one

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The HTML code is hard coded and isn't  from any request or json file

Comment: In which case you need to check the console for errors, as the code you've shown us above works absolutely fine.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Solved. I double checked my code. the html is written inside script of type text/template and this template is rendered before the jquery code. Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest deleting this question then, assuming you're able to

Comment: How to delete the question? But it was useful by your comments

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
$(document).on("click",".switchLang",function (e) {
    console.log("Clicked!")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this might help

```
$(document).on('click', '.switchLang', function (e) {
    console.log("Clicked!")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the document to be ready before adding the click handler, like so:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.switchLang').on('click', function (e) {

           console.log("Clicked!")
       });
    });
```